# Add and delete items of Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've been wanting to learn how to add or delete elements in arrays. I know that it is easier to use Arraylist package on those type of things, but i wanted to learn how to add or delete elements without using it. I have tried creating a code for that, but eventually there has been some errors.

#### The output for my code should be like this:

```
********************^

1 - Search Name
2 - Add Name
3 - Delete Name
Enter mode:2
Enter new name:professor x
Do you want to add a name again?(y/n):y
Enter new name:professor y
Do you want to add a name again?(y/n):n

********************^

1 - Search Name
2 - Add Name
3 - Delete Name
Enter mode: 1
Enter name:professor x
Match found!
```

but my code gives me a `null pointer exception` when searching for a previously entered record:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Practice.Practice1Main.sequentialSearch(Practice1Main.java:95)
at Practice.Practice1Main.mode(Practice1Main.java:18)
at Practice.Practice1Main.getMode(Practice1Main.java:79)
at Practice.Practice1Main.caseTwo(Practice1Main.java:63)
at Practice.Practice1Main.mode(Practice1Main.java:33)
at Practice.Practice1Main.getMode(Practice1Main.java:79)
at Practice.Practice1Main.main(Practice1Main.java:6)
```

My code:

```
package Practice;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice1Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        getMode();
    }
    public static void mode(int mode){
        Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numInput = 2;
        String[] names = new String[numInput];
        String response = "";
        if(mode == 1){
            do{
                int result = sequentialSearch(names, getNames());
                if(result == -1){
                    System.out.print("No match found!\n");
                }else{
                    System.out.print("Match found!\n");
                }
                System.out.print("Do you want to search again?(y/n):");
                response = hold.nextLine();
                if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                    getMode();
                }
            }while(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
        }else if(mode == 2){
            caseTwo(response, names, numInput);
        }else if(mode == 3){
            // TODO: Part 3
        }else{
            System.out.print("ERROR 350\n");
        }
    }

    public static void caseTwo(String response, String[] names, int numInput){
        Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            int x = 0;
            System.out.print("Enter new name:");
            names[x] = hold.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Do you want to add a name again?(y/n):");
            response = hold.nextLine();
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                x++;
                if(x == 2){
                    int add = numInput + 1;
                    names = new String[add];
                    System.out.print("Enter new name:");
                    names[add] = hold.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Do you want to add a name again?(y/n):");
                    response = hold.nextLine();
                    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                        add++;
                    }
                }
            }else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                getMode();
            }else{
                System.out.print("CASE 2 ERROR!\n");
            }
        }while(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }

    public static void getMode(){
        Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
        int mode;
        System.out.print("********************\n");
        System.out.print("1 - Search Name\n");
        System.out.print("2 - Add Name\n");
        System.out.print("3 - Delete Name\n");
        System.out.print("Enter mode:");
        mode = hold.nextInt();
        mode(mode);
    }
    public static String getNames(){
        Scanner hold = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        System.out.print("Enter name:");
        name = hold.nextLine();
        return name;
    }
    public static int sequentialSearch(String[]names,String name){
        int index = 0;
        int element = -1;
        boolean found = false;
        while(!found && index < names.length){
            if(names[index].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                found = true;
                element = index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot resize an array in java

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use ArrayList or you just don't want to? An array has a set size when declared so you cannot "add" or "delete", only reassign values at an index.

Comment: You should fix your post title, you accidentally put in in all CAPS.

Comment: I would just use an array list as others have suggested. It's easier to use, and it'll work how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you enter the `mode()` method, you reinitialize the `names` array. It is why it contains only `null` value, hence the `NullPointerException`. You should make it a field of the class.

Also, by design, its length will always be 2.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList is functionally exactly what you are looking for, and the alternative I'm about to give you is going to do exactly what the ArrayList does in a far less efficient or attractive manner. As a disclaimer, I'm going to say you should learn to use an ArrayList, but I will answer your question on your terms anyway, and you'll simultaneously learn a bit about how an ArrayList works.

To resize an array, you must create a new array no matter what. The most efficient way to do so is probably to use a temporary array to store your data, then reinstantiate your main array variable like such

```
// Inside your adjustable array class. Let's call it "AdvArray"

// A field that's instantiated inside the constructor
int[] exampleArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // create and fill an int array

public void addElement(int element){
    //Make temp array the size of your data and fill it
    int[] tempArray = new int[exampleArray.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<exampleArray.length; i++){
        tempArray[i] = exampleArray[i];
    }

    //reinstantiate exampleArray and fill with old data
    exampleArray = new int[exampleArray.length+1];
    for(int i = 0; i<tempArray.length; i++){
        exampleArray[i] = tempArray[i];
    }

    //Add new element to larger array
    exampleArray[exampleArray.length-1] = element;
}// ===================================================

// Example usage
exampleAdvArray.addElement(500);
```

This method adds one to the end, but you could follow its idea by creating an overflow with an index to add to, and then reverse both processes for a remove method. Then all you need to do is add a getter for elements at any given index, or perhaps even a getArray method that returns the "exampleArray" field.

Or, alternatively, your code looks like this:

```
ArrayList<int> exampleList = new ArrayList<int>();
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    exampleList.add(i);
}
exampleList.add(500);
```

Comment: If you decide to do ArrayList, it also has an indexOf method that does a search and returns the index of an element you enter. It looks like such

    exampleList.indexOf("Professor x"); // returns 0 since it's the first element